# category.php not showing custom post types

Tags: custom-post-types, categories

in my custom post type i've set `'taxonomies' => array('category')`. However, within my category.php page, none of the custom post types are being displayed, only posts.

How do i make ALL post types appear, not just the post?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Custom Post Types on Category Pages](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/10099/custom-post-types-on-category-pages)

Answer (score 1):

just guessing.. did you set "public"=>"true" in register_post_type(..)

Comment: Yep, public is set to true. According to `print_r($wp_query)`, it tells me that it's only querying the posts table. I solved this by putting this at the top of my loop `$cats = new WP_Query(array('post_type'=>'any','category_name'=>single_cat_title('', false)));`

Comment: don't forget about paging in wp_query

Comment: here is better solution using pre_get_posts filter:
http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/18497/displaying-custom-post-type-on-category-pages-but-not-on-blog-listings
- read all comments and change is_home() to is_category() in this custom filter function